# Update UI when Service Worker installed successfully

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Looks like Service Worker runs in a worker context and has no access to the DOM. However, once Service Worker installed, I want my users to know that the app will now work offline. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the Service Worker is in `activated state`, this is the perfect time to display the toast '`Content is cached for offline use`'. Try something below code while registering your service worker.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(function(reg) {
    // updatefound is fired if service-worker.js changes.
    reg.onupdatefound = function() {
      var installingWorker = reg.installing;

      installingWorker.onstatechange = function() {
        switch (installingWorker.state) {
          case 'installed':
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the old content will have been purged and the fresh content will
              // have been added to the cache.
              // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is available; please refresh."
              // message in the page's interface.
              console.log('New or updated content is available.');
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is now available offline!');
            }
            break;

          case 'redundant':
            console.error('The installing service worker became redundant.');
            break;
        }
      };
    };
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.error('Error during service worker registration:', e);
  });
}
```

Comment: Problem is to show a toast I need to access the DOM which I can't do from the Service Worker. `console.log()` is not enough.

Comment: You aren't accessing DOM from SW.This code has to be written while registering service worker.Hence, you can access dom here as  event fired when service worker becomes active.

Comment: Got it. I had to do it on while registering the Service Worker. I was trying to do that from the SW. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After testing [@Prototype Chain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3758710/prototype-chain)'s [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37694786/4306828), I wanted to use `named functions` as opposed to nested `anonymous functions` as event handlers to make code more pleasant to look at for my taste, and hopefully easier to understand later/for others.

But only after spending some time sorting docs, I managed to listen correct events on correct objects. So sharing my working example here in hopes of saving someone else from tedious process.

```
    // make sure that Service Workers are supported.
    if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
            .then(function (registration) {
                console.log("ServiceWorker registered");

                // updatefound event is fired if sw.js changed
                registration.onupdatefound = swUpdated;
            }).catch(function (e) {
            console.log("Failed to register ServiceWorker", e);
        })
    }

    function swUpdated(e) {
        console.log('swUpdated');
        // get the SW which being installed
        var sw = e.target.installing;
        // listen for installation stage changes
        sw.onstatechange = swInstallationStateChanged;
    }

    function swInstallationStateChanged(e) {
        // get the SW which being installed
        var sw = e.target;
        console.log('swInstallationStateChanged: ' + sw.state);

        if (sw.state == 'installed') {
            // is any sw already installed? This function will run 'before' 'SW's activate' handler, so we are checking for any previous sw, not this one.
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                console.log('Content has updated!');
            } else {
                console.log('Content is now available offline!');
            }
        }

        if (sw.state == 'activated') {
            // new|updated SW is now activated.
            console.log('SW is activated!');
        }
    }
```