# How can I claim a client when initializing a ServiceWorker to prevent having to reload the page?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm having trouble to wrap my head around the [Clients.claim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/claim) API of the ServiceWorker. From what I understand ([here](https://davidwalsh.name/offline-recipes-service-workers) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/skipWaiting)) I can call `claim()` on the service worker *activate* event to prevent having to refresh the page to initialize the ServiceWorker. I can't get it to work though and always end up having to refresh. Here's my code:

Inside the service worker:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {

  self.skipWaiting();

  event.waitUntil(caches.open(CURRENT_CACHE_DICT.prefetch)
    .then(function(cache) {
      var cachePromises = PREFETCH_URL_LIST.map(function(prefetch_url) {
        var url = new URL(prefetch_url, location.href),
          request = new Request(url, {mode: 'no-cors'});

        return fetch(request).then(function(response) {
          if (response.status >= 400) {
            throw new Error('request for ' + prefetch_url +
              ' failed with status ' + response.statusText);
          }
          return cache.put(prefetch_url, response);
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.error('Not caching ' + prefetch_url + ' due to ' + error);
        });
      });

      return Promise.all(cachePromises).then(function() {
        console.log('Pre-fetching complete.');
      });
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Pre-fetching failed:', error);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {

  // claim the scope immediately
  // XXX does not work?
  //self.clients.claim();

  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim()
    .then(caches.keys)
    .then(function(cache_name_list) {
      return Promise.all(
        cache_name_list.map(function() {...}
      );
    })
  );
});
```

The above runs but I'm ending up having to refresh and found an`Illegal invocation` error in the Chrome ServiceWorker internals. If I remove the `clients.claim` from the `waitUntil` handler and uncomment the previous one, I get no errors, but I still have to refresh. The debugger shows:

```
Console: {"lineNumber":128,"message":"Pre-fetching complete.","message_level":1,"sourceIdentifier":3,"sourceURL":""}
Console: {"lineNumber":0,"message":"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Illegal invocation","message_level":3,"sourceIdentifier":1,"sourceURL":""}
```

The refresh is triggered like this:

```
function waitForInstallation(registration) {
    return new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (registration.installing) {
      registration.installing.addEventListener('statechange', function(e) {
        if (e.target.state == 'installed') {
          resolve();
        } else if (e.target.state == 'redundant') {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  });
}

// refreshing should not be necessary if scope is claimed on activate
function claimScope(installation) {
  return new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      reject(new Error("Please refresh to initialize serviceworker."));
    }
  });
}

rJS(window)
  .declareMethod('render', function (my_option_dict) {
    var gadget = this;

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      return new RSVP.Queue()
        .push(function () {
          return navigator.serviceWorker.register(
            my_option_dict.serviceworker_url,
            {scope: my_option_dict.scope}
          );
        })
        .push(function (registration) {
          return waitForInstallation(registration);
        })
        .push(function (installation) {
          return claimScope(installation);
        })
        .push(null, function (my_error) {
          console.log(my_error);
          throw my_error;
        });
    } else {
      throw new Error("Browser does not support serviceworker.");
    }
  });
```

**Question**:
How do I correctly prevent the page from having to be refreshed to activate the ServiceWorker using `claim`? None of the links I found mentioned having to explicitly check for `controller` but I assume if a ServiceWorker is active it would have a controller accessible.

Thanks for shedding some info.

**EDIT:**
Figured it out with help from below. This made it work for me:

```
// runs while an existing worker runs or nothing controls the page (update here)
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {

  event.waitUntil(caches.open(CURRENT_CACHE_DICT.dictionary)
    .then(function(cache) {
      var cache_promise_list = DICTIONARY_URL_LIST.map(function(prefetch_url) {...});

      return Promise.all(cache_promise_list).then(function() {
        console.log('Pre-fetching complete.');
      });
    })
    .then(function () {

      // force waiting worker to become active worker (claim)
      self.skipWaiting();

    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Pre-fetching failed:', error);
    })
  );
});

// runs active page, changes here (like deleting old cache) breaks page
self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {

  event.waitUntil(caches.keys()
    .then(function(cache_name_list) {
      return Promise.all(
        cache_name_list.map(function(cache_name) { ... })  
      );
    })
    .then(function () {
      return self.clients.claim();
    })
  );
});
```

Triggering script:

```
var SW = navigator.serviceWorker;    

function installServiceWorker(my_option_dict) {
  return new RSVP.Queue()
    .push(function () {
      return SW.getRegistration();
    })
    .push(function (is_registered_worker) {

      // XXX What if this isn't mine?
      if (!is_registered_worker) {
        return SW.register(
          my_option_dict.serviceworker_url, {
            "scope": my_option_dict.scope
          }
        );   
      }
      return is_registered_worker;
    });
}

function waitForInstallation(registration) {
  return new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (registration.installing) {
      // If the current registration represents the "installing" service
      // worker, then wait until the installation step completes (during
      // which any defined resources are pre-fetched) to continue.
      registration.installing.addEventListener('statechange', function(e) {
        if (e.target.state == 'installed') {
          resolve(registration);
        } else if (e.target.state == 'redundant') {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    } else {
      // Otherwise, if this isn't the "installing" service worker, then
      // installation must have beencompleted during a previous visit to this
      // page, and the any resources will already have benn pre-fetched So
      // we can proceed right away.
      resolve(registration);
    }
  });
}

// refreshing should not be necessary if scope is claimed on activate
function claimScope(registration) {
  return new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (registration.active.state === 'activated') {
      resolve();
    } else {
      reject(new Error("Please refresh to initialize serviceworker."));
    }
  });
}

rJS(window)

  .ready(function (my_gadget) {
    my_gadget.property_dict = {};
  })

  .declareMethod('render', function (my_option_dict) {
    var gadget = this;

    if (!SW) {
      throw new Error("Browser does not support serviceworker.");
    }

    return new RSVP.Queue()
      .push(function () {
        return installServiceWorker(my_option_dict),
      })
      .push(function (my_promise) {
        return waitForInstallation(my_promise);
      })
      .push(function (my_installation) {
        return claimScope(my_installation);
      })
      .push(function () {
        return gadget;
      })
      .push(null, function (my_error) {
        console.log(my_error);
        throw my_error;
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you are seem to be getting the error because of a typo in your code. See notes about it at the bottom.

Besides, [`skipWaiting()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/skipWaiting#Example) and [`Clients.claim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/claim) *does* both install and activate *new* SW with a single request. But quite naturally you will only get static assets like css after you reload.

So, even when equipped with `skipWaiting()` and `Clients.claim()`, you need two page reloads to see updated `static` content like new html or styles;

**Page load #1**

- Request to `sw.js` is made, and [since SW contents is changed](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers#update-a-service-worker) `install` event is fired on it.
- Also `activate` event is fired, since you have `self.skipWaiting()` in your `install` handler.
- Consequently, your `activate` handler run and there is your `self.clients.claim()` call. Which will order the SW to take over the control of all the clients which under control of it's predecessor.
- At this point, assets in cache are updated and your pages are all controlled by new service worker. Any Ajax request in range of service worker will return newly cached responses, for example.

**Page load #2**

Your app loads, and your SW responds from cache by hijacking the requests as usual. But now caches are up-to-date, and user gets to use app *completely* with new assets.

**The error you are getting**

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Illegal invocation` error must be due to a missing a parenthesis in your `activate` handler;

```
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim()
    .then(caches.keys)
    .then(function(cache_name_list) {
      return Promise.all(
        cache_name_list.map(function() {...}
      ); <-- Here is our very lonely single parenthesis.
    })
  );
```

That error should go away if you fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the lonely parenthesis :) So page load #1 gives control and page load #2 gives me new static content loaded on the #2 load. Thus if I only needed control to communicate via postMessage and am not caching any requests, then load #1 would be enough? Do you know why `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` is still undefined on load #1 even though I claim? Thanks

Comment: Haha, you are welcome =) You can listen for service worker activation, so you can execute your code when service worker is activated/available. I have updated one of my recent answers to cover that case. [You can go to the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41916335/4306828) and check `if (sw.state == 'activated')` statement in the last section.

Comment: regarding the parenthesis. It should be a single one, because it closes the `Promise.all()`. No?

Comment: No, it is closing the `cache_name_list.map()`. And I have found it out by copying the code to my IDE. Do you not use a modern IDE? If you do it must also show it you too. Plus I have tried as how it is and with an other parenthesis. Since you ask, I think there is still errors with your code? Your code works good for me with an additional parenthesis.

Comment: I'm developing on a Chromebook, so currently Ace Editor with JSLint. Works ok-ish-ly. Regarding the code, I think I have it now. I'll post another edit.

Comment: Finally got it working. My error was checking for the "wrong" activated. I should have checked on the registration I'm creating, which I'm doing in the edit above now. Thanks again for helping!