# How to get the latest resources from service worker cache(right now on 2nd load resources are updating)?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

How to get the latest resources from service worker cache, I am trying to update the cached resources for the first refresh, as of now my resources are updating only on 2nd refresh, any help would be great to update the resources only on first refresh.

```js
var CACHE_NAME = 'Bcache-E4'; 
var FilesToCache = [
  '/'
];
 
// Install SW
self.addEventListener('install', function (e) { 
    console.log('[Service Worker] Install');
    e.waitUntil(
      caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function (cache) { 
          //console.log('[Service Worker] Caching app shell');
          return cache.addAll(FilesToCache);
      }).then(function(e){
        return self.skipWaiting();
      })
    );
});

// Activating service worker
self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Activate');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(keyList) {
      return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
        // Removing old cache
        if (key !== CACHE_NAME) {
          console.log('[Service Worker] Removing old cache', key);
          return caches.delete(key);
        }
      }));
    })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

// Fetch resources & Check Returning source
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
          if (response) {
              console.log(
                '[fetch] Returning from Service Worker cache: ',
                event.request.url
              );
              return response;
          }
          console.log('[fetch] Returning from server: ', event.request.url);
          return fetch(event.request);
      }
    )
  );
  
    event.waitUntil(
        update(event.request)
        .then(refresh)
     );
});

// TO Update Request
function update(request) {
  return caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function (cache) {
    return fetch(request).then(function (response) {
      return cache.put(request, response.clone()).then(function () {
        return response;
      });
    });
  });
} 

// TO Refresh Response
function refresh(response) {
  return self.clients.matchAll().then(function (clients) {
    clients.forEach(function (client) {
      var message = {
        type: 'refresh',
        url: response.url,
        eTag: response.headers.get('ETag')
      };
    client.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message));
    });
  });
}
```

**strong text**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I claim a client when initializing a ServiceWorker to prevent having to reload the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912166/how-can-i-claim-a-client-when-initializing-a-serviceworker-to-prevent-having-to)

Comment: Short answer: you cannot. At least 2 refreshed are required. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41915695/4306828) explains in dept why and how.